# Trouble updating Nextcloud from version 23.0.0 to 23.0.5

Tags: nextcloud

as I said in the title, I am having trouble updating Nextcloud from version 23.0.0 to 23.0.5.

The system is running on a KVM virtual machine. To upgrade, these are the steps I make:

1. ssh into the server
2. `cd /var/www/nextcloud`
3. enable maintenance mode: `sudo -u www-data php occ maintenance:mode --on`
4. Backing up the machine
5. Change files ownership so they can be written: `chown -R www-data /var/www/nextcloud`
6. Update it: `sudo -u www-data php updater/updater.phar`
7. Then, I simply roll back the permissions and disable the maintenance mode

The system updates. However, when I log in and go to the administration overview, I get a warning saying:

> Invalid UUIDs of LDAP users or groups have been found. Please review your "Override UUID detection" settings in the Expert part of the LDAP configuration and use "occ ldap:update-uuid" to update them.

When I run the command they say "`occ ldap:update-uuid`" the console outputs this:

```
# sudo -u www-data php occ ldap:update-uuid 
8/8 [============================] 100% 
No record was updated.
For 8 records, the UUID could not be saved to database. Double-check your configuration.
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Another possibility is getting the UUIDs and replacing them or even removing them if they are not needed. But still, I don't know how to get to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Some LDAP Groups were deleted, and this change did not propagate to NextCloud.

When running `sudo -u www-data php occ ldap:update-uuid`, you can add `--verbose` to see what is happening.

In my case, it returned eight groups.

The solution was to open MySQL, select the NextCloud database and then delete the invalid groups in the table `oc_ldap_group_mapping`. To achieve this, just run:

```
delete from oc_ldap_group_mapping where directory_uuid like "invalidated_%"
```

This solution may also apply to LDAP users with invalid UUIDs, but I can't confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution!

It works also for `oc_ldap_user_mapping` with invalid UUIDs.

1. `Select * from oc_ldap_user_mapping where directory_uuid like "invalidated_%"`
2. `Delete from oc_ldap_user_mapping where directory_uuid like "invalidated_%"`